# Action bar - ifRoom option leaving too much space

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-search

I have a problem on my Action bar, I tried to setup a [search view](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) on it in order to get a a search bar expandable.

This is woking well except the fact that I had to set all the other menu items with the option `ifRoom` in order to let the search field take all the room when the search icon is clicked.

This part also worked well except the fact that too many menu items got pushed into the menu overflow, only 2 icons remained on the vertical screen (including the search bar).

I did another test on another activity having 5 menu items:

1. In the first case, I set all of them with `android:showAsAction="always"`
2. In the second case, I set all of them with ``android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Here are the results:

**Case 1:**

[image: always case]

**Case 2:**

[image: ifRoom case]

Why if I use `ifRoom`, only 2 icons are displayed while actually 5 could easily fill the place?

Because of this, I have only one menu item available beside my search view item...

Thanks!

Comment: Why if I use ifRoom, only 2 icons are displayed?? ----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832302/1168654

Comment: I checked your link, but it does not answer my question. I know it is related to the screen size, but here I have for example far enough space for more than 2 icons.

Comment: In the XML file, you can request a menu item to appear as an action item by declaring android:showAsAction="ifRoom" for the <item> element. This way, the menu item appears in the action bar for quick access only if there is room available. If there's not enough room, the item appears in the overflow menu. hope you understand. for more detail check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Yes I have that, the other options appear in the overflow menu, but I would prefer if they could remain on the action bar. The menu overflow is not directly reachable.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I think his problem (and mine too) is not about the "ifRoom" setting, but about the fact that there appears to be enough room for the icons however Android is putting them in the overflow menu (presumably because Android doesn't think there is enough room).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like its a design decision:

**Jake Wharton Says:**

> When contained within the action bar there is a finite maximum of
>   action items based on the device's density-independent width. The
>   action items can also not cover more than half the width of the action
>   bar.

From [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/9dfnA2hnNXg).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this limit was in place. I found out that here are detailed some examples and the number of icons displayed: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file, you can request a `MenuItem` to appear as an action item by declaring `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for the `<item>` element. This way, the `MenuItem` appears in the `ActionBar` for quick access only if there is room available. If there's not enough room, the item appears in the overflow menu.

so you answer is:

> use "ifRoom" to request that an item appear in the action bar, but
>   allow the system to move it into the overflow menu when there's not
>   enough room.(when space is limited on smaller screens).

You can use `android:showAsAction="always"` to show all menu in `ActionBar`.

Comment: Thanks but as explained above, I would prefer the icons to be displayed in the visible action bar and not in the overflow if there is room available for it.

Comment: i explain here because you understand why we can't show all icons in actionbar using ifroom. in sort you can't do that using 'ifroom'

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of icons for "ifRoom" option is 5 (five) even when I moved to my 100 inch screen size tablet :-) and desperately rotate it on landscape
see the link from Jake Wharton's answer (Thank you !) http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html