# How to allow more visible items on a menu in android before collapse?

Tags: android

Today, even in a large screen tablet, the menu items appear to be limited to 5 items and then it collapses. But I would like to use more space and show more icons.

Is there a easy way to achieve that? Or should I extend and customize the android.view.Menu in some way?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The action bar is designed have a finite maximum of action items based on the device's density-independent width. The action items can also not cover more than half the width of the action bar.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772518/3549440) answer.