# Couldn't show items with AppCompat library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I am having some troubles to show items in the ActionBar with AppCompat.

This code works on a normal actionbar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Se connecter"
        android:visible="true">
    </item>

</menu>
```

But with the AppCompat library the item isn't shown..

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`showAsAction` is not in the android xml namespace for API < 11 try something like the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />
</menu>
```

Note that I've added `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` in menu attributes and changed the namespace of `showAsAction` from `android` to `yourapp`.

More reading here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: this isn't well documented on the android website, but this helped me out, thanks!