# MenuInflater not working - menu not showing

Tags: android

My menu is not showing in the ActionBar (`onCreateOptionsMenu`) is called properly. The icon and string are available. The code works fine in my other projects. I am using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` for android:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    Log.i("onCreate", "menu");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            Intent addIntent = new Intent(this, RoomAddActivity.class);
            startActivity(addIntent);
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_add"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Menu XML should have root menu element. Show whole menu XML file, please.

Comment: Ups, it was somehow hidden. Updated.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386642/couldnt-show-items-with-appcompat-library

Comment: Thank you, that works. Should mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return true explicitly:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    Log.i("onCreate", "menu");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Updated**:
By the way, you are not obliged to call super method. As to my experience it works all right without it.