# Show Menu item always in support action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, optionmenu

[image]I am working on android application . I have implemented supported action bar in it .I want to show option menu item always . But it is not showing . it is showing in drop down menu . my code for menu item given below.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_post"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"

    />
```

And code of ActionBar Activity is given below:-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be you are missing a namespace.Please Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)
you should add `showAsAction` attribute to `always` or `ifRoom`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: There is no effect of this line.

Comment: updated code ? and can you show the overflow icon also as screenshot

Comment: I have added sample image . I want to show permanent button. not drop  down.

Comment: Thank you kabira . i got my answer.

Answer (score 46):

If you use the `AppCompat` ActionBar, you have to change your layout in this way:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_post"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

`showAsAction` attribute will work only with a custom prefixe, see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems). According to it:

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using AppCompat library. When i use `app:showAsAction="always"` , it does not give me any result. All the menu comes under the drop down. But if i put `android:showAsAction="always"` even if i use AppCompat, then i get the result as expected but with a red line warning under the statement. What should be done in such case?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the different values of `android:showAsAction` property in android menu xml file..

to show all time visible menu on actionbar, you should go with `android:showAsAction="always"`..

You can also use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` but it will show the menu in action bar not always but it will show according to different screen size.

**Edited**

Ref: [Menu items doesn't show up on the actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380085/menu-items-doesnt-show-up-on-the-actionbar)

Try with the below code then..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_lang"
        app:showAsAction="always" <!-- app:showAsAction="ifRoom" -->
        android:title="@string/menu_lang"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_lang"/>
</menu>
```

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: If you are in Eclipse sometimes the XML will show an error, you have to clean the project and the error will go away as long as you don't modify the XML again.  If you do, clean project again and error will go away.

Answer (score 5):

remove this line `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

use **`android:showAsAction="always"`** instead of `app:showAsAction="always"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_filter"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is 2+ years old, but for completeness, if you want to set this in code use the following:

```
menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

other options are

```
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
```