# Show action Always doesn't work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

All icons are shown in the overflow menu, but I want them on actionbar view.
I have tried several things but still getting the issue. Here is my xml file:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
          android:id="@+id/addnewqmsmenu"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="Add New"
          android:icon="@drawable/addqms5"/>
 </menu>
```

Comment: try setting `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: i have tried  but it also didnt work.

Comment: Do you use Toolbar or ActionBar? Because app-prefix refers to Toolbar and android-prefix to ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/addnewqmsmenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/addqms5"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380085/menu-items-doesnt-show-up-on-the-actionbar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512644/action-buttons-doesnt-show-up-on-action-bar

Comment: i have tried all these but still getting this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and add extra `xmlns` attribute for your menu and try `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/addnewqmsmenu"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Add New"
            android:icon="@drawable/addqms5"/>

 </menu>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: yes but you have mentioned yourapp in xmlns attribute and you have used app:showAsAction . so you have to use yourapp:showAsAction

Comment: yourapp should be app  :)

Comment: which activity class you are extending?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer its because of AppCompatResource . i solved it like that

```
    <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     >


   <item
    android:id="@+id/buttonqms"
    android:title="computer"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/addqms5"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    </menu>
```

Comment: Glad to hear .Move ahead