# How to arrange menu items in action bar to my liking ?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, android-actionbar

i was wondering if anyone could tell me how to choose which menu items go in to the actiobar and which ones go into the overflow menu, i have five menu items and the ones i want in the actionbar go in the overflow and the one i want in the overflow are in the actiobar.
How can i rearrange the actionbars?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do.
First you can set the flag

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

This will show items if there is room, if not they will be placed in the overflow menu.

Second, the XML file is scanned linearly. So just put your actions that you in the overflow menu to the bottom.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) states

> Menu items that are not promoted to an action item are available in the overflow menu, revealed by
>   either the device Menu button (when available) or by an "overflow menu" button in the action bar
>   (when the device does not include a Menu button).

Here is also an good post with more information.
[How to force overflow menu on android actionbar compat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758263/how-to-force-overflow-menu-on-android-actionbar-compat)

Comment: you, know i looked at my code before you answered and realized that the android:showAsAction="ifRoom" is the problem.