# How to force the menu to be inside 3 dotted button on Android Actionbar 4.x?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know that I can the menu to be inside 3 dotted button on Android Actionbar by this way:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

But then, when I run it in Android 4.x, the 3 dotted button is not shown. Then I read the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758263/how-to-force-overflow-menu-on-android-actionbar-compat):

> The action overflow menu is only available when there is no hard menu
>   button available on the device.

He suggested to use `ActionBarSherlock` and use its `ForceOverFlow` theme but later there was an issue that need this theme to be removed.

Is there any other possible solution to force menu to be inside 3 dotted button on Android 4.x with physical menu button?

Comment: Since the users of devices with MENU buttons are used to pressing the MENU button to get the overflow, why do you want to do this? Why is this beneficial to those users?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, actually I'm still in design process of my app and I want the design of my app is one for all Android OS that I will support. But then, I will leave how the Android system will handle the overflow menu as it is. Thanks!