# Problems adding menu items into ActionBar using HoloEveryWhere library

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere, android-actionbar-compat

I am following the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Where it says that:

> If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions
>   as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available
>   from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is provided by the
>   Support Library and you must define your own XML namespace and use
>   that namespace as the attribute prefix. (A custom XML namespace should
>   be based on your app name, but it can be any name you want and is only
>   accessible within the scope of the file in which you declare it.)

So I define following `main_activity_actions.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="temp"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="temp"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

And I get following errors:

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'`

I am using `HoloEveryWhere` library in my project. Project build target is 19. Manifest has:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Any suggestions how to get the custom namespace working?

Adding reference into `android-support-v7-appcompat` library gives tons of already defined errors:

```
error: Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined    abc_attrs.xml   /Myapp/HoloEverywhere-master/library/res/values line 71 Android AAPT Problem
```

Thanks.

Comment: read this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/9040857/1937802

Comment: have you referenced appcompat

Comment: I am not using ABS and not going to, since Jake said that the project is done and HoloEveryWhere is continued.

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried copying android-support-v7-appcompat.jar under libs folder, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Niko wrong. its a library project and should be referenced

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried copying android-support-v7-appcompat.jar under libs folder, but it didn't help
```

You need to reference AppCompat in your android project instead of adding it as a jar to libs folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Just like how you reference google play services you need to referecen appcompat the same way.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Done, but now gettting tons of already defined errors by HoloEveryWhere:
error: Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined abc_attrs.xml /myApp/HoloEverywhere-master/library/res/values line 71 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: @Niko i have not used HoloEveryWhere. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html. For holo themes you can refer this link

Comment: @Niko is holoeverywhere dependent on ABS?

Comment: Yes, but since Holo came in API level 11 and my min target is 8, I cannot use it native way.

Comment: @Niko read the link i posted full. also i believe holoeverywhere is dependent on ABS. I am not sure though

Comment: It seems that HoloEveryWhere has some references to ActionBar attrs, since this multiple defined error came up.

Comment: @Niko try using abs with holo or completely switch to appcompat. this is a suggestion as i am not aware of how to use holoeverywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There was no need to use custom namespace in first place. Simply using `android` namespace `android:showAsAction="always"` works fine, tested with emulator API level 8 and 2.3x device and 4.4 device.

Comment: Could you please be more specific how is this achieved. Nameliy "showAsAction" does not exist in API level until 11.